# Can anyone explain how to use OpenACC in GCC?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am using WSL Ubuntu. And use GCC to compile my C++ code.

I am trying to use OpenACC to parallelize my code. I heard that I can use OpenACC with GCC.

So after I install Ubuntu, I installed GCC.

And then I typed as follows:

```
$ g++ -fopenacc -o t testfile.cpp
```

As far as I know, `-fopenacc` should enable me to use OpenACC inside my code.

However, I got an message saying:

```
lto-wrapper: fatal error: could not find accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/ (consider using ‘-B’)
```

So I guess I missed something.

Does anyone know how to use OpenACC with GCC?

---

**Edited:**

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-9-offload-nvptx
```

And then the error message is now changed to:

```
lto1: error: ‘-fcf-protection=full’ is not supported for this target
mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-9 returned 1 exit status

compilation terminated.

lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.

/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What about installing a GCC with an OpenACC support using Spack as described on the [OpenACC website](https://www.openacc.org/tools/gcc-for-openacc)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am downloading using Spack. Hope this works... I already had GCC 9 do I need to uninstall the previous version in order to use this new one?

Comment: The purpose of Spack here is to install a custom GCC version patched with the support of nvptx/OpenACC. So it could be better to avoid conflicts in the installed version of GCC if possible (especially for complex builds). Anyway, you can check the version of GCC once installed to check if this is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I got one step further with:

```
gcc-10 -O2 -ffast-math -fopenacc -fopt-info-all-omp -fcf-protection=none -foffload=nvptx laplace2dkernels.c
```

but just to find the next problem:

```
gcc-10: fatal error: GCC is not configured to support nvptx as offload target
compilation terminated
```

So it seems they only compiled it for AMD GCN.
If you use

```
gcc-10 -O2 -ffast-math -fopenacc -fopt-info-all-omp -fcf-protection=none -foffload=nvptx-none laplace2dkernels.c

>laplace2dkernels.c:74:9: optimized: assigned OpenACC seq loop parallelism
>/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYd0cZe.crtoffloadtable.o: warning: relocation against >`__offload_vars_end' in read-only section `.rodata'
```

It compiles but then when running it misses:

```
libgomp: while loading libgomp-plugin-gcn.so.1: libgomp-plugin-gcn.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do not need to install those libraries because I want to get it to run with my Nvidia card.

With the PGI compilers everything worked fine.

**NOTE:** I am also using WSL and special NVIDIA drivers to allow for GPU passthrough.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I was struggling for days... I was also trying to install pgi compiler but I have no idea how to install it using WSL Ubuntu. Can I ask you how to install it? Is there any instruction that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me for a Tiny C++ stencil code with OpenACC directives, after installing gcc-10-offload-nvptx:

```
g++ -c -g -O -fopenacc -foffload=nvptx-none -fcf-protection=none -foffload=-misa=sm_35 -fno-stack-protector stencil_acc.cxx

g++ -o stencil_acc -g -O -fopenacc -foffload=nvptx-none -fcf-protection=none -foffload=-misa=sm_35 -fno-stack-protector util.o stencil_acc.o
```